How to delete Image from digital ocean space folder with C#?
I'm trying to delete the image from my digital ocean space folder, But this delete the folder not the image.
        // DigitalOcean Spaces credentials
        string spacesKey = "YOUR_SPACES_ACCESS_KEY";
        string spacesSecret = "YOUR_SPACES_SECRET_KEY";
        string spacesBucket = "YOUR_SPACES_BUCKET_NAME";
        string folderName = "folder-to-delete";

        // Create HttpClient instance
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Configure base URL and authorization headers
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{spacesBucket}.YOUR_REGION.digitaloceanspaces.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {spacesKey}");

        // Send DELETE request to delete folder
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.DeleteAsync(folderName);

        // Check if the request was successful
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Folder '{folderName}' deleted successfully.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to delete folder'{folderName}'. 
            Status code:{response.StatusCode}");
        }


can anybody tell how to do this, please ?
